# How to fill value in specific column ？

Tags: python, dataframe

For example, in the data, there are NAN values in both profit and country columns. How to fill in the vacancy of profit as 0, while the country does not change.[enter image description here][1]

I tried:

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)
```

set Groupby as Country, Metrics as Sum(profit)
but the result:

> Country          Sum(profit)
>
> 0                  0
>
> httg                0
>
> sdffs               0

In this way, all vacancies will be filled with 0 (including countries that are not needed), and after groupby, there will be an additional category of 0 in Country conlumn(no need).

Answer (score 1):

> How to fill value in specific column？

Select the column you want to operate on, and call `replace()` with `inplace=True`:

```
df['Sum(profit)'].replace(np.nan, 0.0, inplace=True)
```